# XSLT parsing nodes with colon in name into CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am new to XML and XSLT. I've searched google for a couple of hours now and have yet to figure this one out....

Here is a snippet of the XML code I am trying to parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gam:gameboxscore xmlns:gam="http://leaguemanager.beacontender.com/plugin/feed/sport/usftbl/gameboxscore">
    <gam:lastUpdatedOn>2017-01-08 12:22:22 AM</gam:lastUpdatedOn>
    <gam:game>
        <gam:date>2017-01-07</gam:date>
        <gam:time>8:15PM</gam:time>
        <gam:awayTeam>
            <gam:ID>61</gam:ID>
            <gam:City>Detroit</gam:City>
            <gam:Name>Lions</gam:Name>
            <gam:Abbreviation>DET</gam:Abbreviation>
        </gam:awayTeam>
        <gam:homeTeam>
            <gam:ID>79</gam:ID>
            <gam:City>Seattle</gam:City>
            <gam:Name>Seahawks</gam:Name>
            <gam:Abbreviation>SEA</gam:Abbreviation>
        </gam:homeTeam>
        <gam:location>CenturyLink Field</gam:location>
    </gam:game>
    <gam:quarterSummary>
        <gam:quarter number="1">
        <gam:awayScore>0</gam:awayScore>
        <gam:homeScore>0</gam:homeScore>
        <gam:scoring/>
    </gam:quarter>
    <gam:quarter number="2">
        <gam:awayScore>3</gam:awayScore>
        <gam:homeScore>10</gam:homeScore>
        <gam:scoring>
            <gam:scoringPlay>
                <gam:time>7:46</gam:time>
                <gam:teamAbbreviation>SEA</gam:teamAbbreviation>
                <gam:playDescription>(7:14) R.Wilson pass short right to P.Richardson for 2 yards, TOUCHDOWN. Penalty on DET-T.Wilson, Defensive Pass Interference, declined.</gam:playDescription>
            </gam:scoringPlay>
        </gam:scoring>
    </gam:quarter>
    </gam:quarterSummary>
<gam:gameboxscore
```

Here is my XSLT code. I am attempting to create a CSV from the XML file. It creates the CSV, but only has the defined column headers and no actual data.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:gam="http://leaguemanager.beacontender.com/plugin/feed/sport/usftbl/gameboxscore"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text<GameDate;AwayTeam;HomeTeam;ScoringTeam;playDescription</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:for-each select="/gam:gameboxscore">
   <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../gam:game/gam:date"/>
   <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../gam:game/gam:awayteam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
   <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../gam:game/gam:hometeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
   <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../gam:quartersummary/gam:quarter/gam:scoring/gam:scoringplay/gam:teamabbreviation"/>
   <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="../gam:quartersummary/gam:quarter/gam:scoring/gam:scoringplay/gam:teamabbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both your XML and XSLT have syntax errors. The last line of the XML should be a `</gam:gameboxscore>` tag and in the XSLT the line that outputs the header is bad.  Did you copy/paste this from your actual files or retype it? If you retyped it, [edit] the post and copy/paste in the _acutal_ XML and XSLT.  Beyond the syntax issues there's another problem.  Your XSLT implies you expect to have more than one `<gam:gameboxscore>` section but this cannot be as that tag is the root, and there can be only one root.  The solution will be easy but you need to post actual XML and XSLT to get help.

Comment: BTW, don't take my comments personally. You've actually posted a very good first question and I want to see this get an answer as soon as we understand what you're _actually_ trying to accomplish.

Comment: Indeed, according to your needs, the result would be a one row csv. I'm thinking XML has many `<gam:game>` nodes.

Comment: I don't take it personally. I modified the XML so I did not have to post the entire 340,000 characters. I may have forgotten to type the ending nodes correctly. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of syntax errors. Let me take this as an example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../gam:game/gam:awayteam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
```

1. This cannot work, because you are in the context of
   `gam:gameboxscore` - and `gam:game` is not the *parent* of
   `gam:gameboxscore` ( the `..` step is short for `parent::node()`). You
   want to use:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="./gam:game/gam:awayteam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
   ```

   or simply:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="gam:game/gam:awayteam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
   ```

   to select the *child* `gam:game` as the first location step.
2. XML is case-sensitive: `gam:awayteam` does not select
   `gam:awayTeam`.

Now, if you try:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:game/gam:awayTeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
```

you will get an actual value. Correct the rest of your `select` expressions accordingly.

---

P.S. I did not understand the structure of your input or, for that matter, of your output. Will there ever be only one game? And only one scoring play? If so, you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:template match="/gam:gameboxscore">
    <xsl:text>GameDate;AwayTeam;HomeTeam;ScoringTeam;playDescription&#13;&#10;"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:game/gam:date"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:game/gam:awayTeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:game/gam:homeTeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:quarterSummary/gam:quarter/gam:scoring/gam:scoringPlay/gam:teamAbbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="gam:quarterSummary/gam:quarter/gam:scoring/gam:scoringPlay/gam:playDescription"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="/gam:gameboxscore">
    <xsl:text>GameDate;AwayTeam;HomeTeam;ScoringTeam;playDescription&#13;&#10;"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="game" select="gam:game" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$game/gam:date"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$game/gam:awayTeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$game/gam:homeTeam/gam:Abbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="scoring-play" select="gam:quarterSummary/gam:quarter/gam:scoring/gam:scoringPlay" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$scoring-play/gam:teamAbbreviation"/>
    <xsl:text>";"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$scoring-play/gam:playDescription"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The outputs you gave me is returning the first scoring play (which was the only one I included in the XML example so that makes sense). What I am really needing is to grab each scoring play that occurred. There could be 0 scoring plays in a quarter, and many scoring plays in a quarter. 

Another thing I am wanting is for GameDate, AwayTeam, etc. to be a different column in excel. And the corresponding data I am selecting to be under that column.

Thank you for the input!

Comment: I cannot answer that without seeing an example of input with multiple scoring plays and the corresponding expected output. And I did not understand the "another thing" at all. I suggest you post a new question with your current (i.e. corrected for the above) attempt.